# Вынуть String Resource с другой локалью из с вручную созданного контекста

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, context

Я хочу в рантайме в зависимости от выбранного пользователем языка вынимать string-ресурсы из определенной локали.
Для этого я написал такую функцию:

```
    fun getLocalizedString(requestedLocale: Locale, resourceId: Int, context: Context): String? {
        val newConfig = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
        newConfig.setLocale(requestedLocale)
        val newContext = context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig)
        Log.d(TAG_NATIVE_LANG, "getLocaleStringResource: check new context: ${newContext.resources.configuration.locale}") // показывает локаль
        val newString = newContext.resources.getString(resourceId)
        Log.d(TAG_NATIVE_LANG, "getLocaleStringResource: check new string = $newString") //показывает вынутую стрингу

        return newString
    }
```

Проблемка в том, что она срабатвает, но не всегда. То есть в `newContext` прокинута правильная локаль всегда (это видно по логам, который показывает локаль). Но в конечном счете примерно в 80% случаев функция возвращает стрингу на дефолтном языке (даже если в newConfig была прокинута правильная локаль).
Я не понимаю почему так происходит, но подозреваю что это как-то связано с особенностями работы Context-a.

Может кто-то сможет подкинуть идею, "куда копать"? Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте возвращать сразу вот такое: `return context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig).getString(resourceId)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все равно работало нестабильно. В итоге создал стринги для обоих язков в одном основном файле string.xml и создал дата-класс LocalizedString(stringTag: StringTag, resIdRu: Int, resIdUa: Int), и в зависимости от языка вытаскиваю один из двух стрингов. (StringTag это enum.)